# Upgrading AWS RDS DB from MySQL5 to MySQL8 - cannot connect in deployed environment

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a PHP application running on AWS Elastic Beanstalk that, up to this point, has been utilizing a MySQL 5.7 RDS DB. I've attempted to upgrade that DB to MySQL 8 by creating a read replica of my MySQL 5.7 DB, upgrading it to MySQL 8, and then promoting that read replica to its own instance. The new MySQL 8 DB instance has a different connection string but maintains the same username, password, etc that the old MySQL 5.7 DB instance had, so none of those settings should need to be changed.

When I am running my application locally -- having updated my .env file to connect with the new connection string for the MySQL 8 DB -- everything works great. My application runs as expected, all of my data in the DB/application looks good, and I'm able to read from and write to the DB without issue. All good there.

However, when I try and push the updated connection variables to Elastic Beanstalk -- having made the update to my .env file to utilize the new connection string -- I get a 503 back with previous little error info. Within my AWS console, I see that "Instance ELB health state has been 'OutOfService' for xx time ... and the 503 I get back just says "Service Unavailable: Back-end server is at capacity."

I know more info may be needed here, but I am trying to figure out: is there something else I need to check in my Elastic Beanstalk configuration to allow connection to the MySQL 8 DB? I am a bit of an AWS rookie and am struggling to determine how to troubleshoot.

FWIW: my environment is open for public access/does not require a VPN to connect locally or otherwise, so I don't think it's a security issue.

Any help, guidance, or ideas would be much appreciate -- thanks much in advance.

Comment: You should check your application's error log and metrics; there may be more details for the problem. AWS have a doc about how to set up Elastic Beanstalk and CloudWatch Logs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.cloudwatchlogs.html. Also, you should compare MySQL parameters on remote and local. See if there are no critical differences between your RDS parameter group and local MySQL server's parameters (e.g. charset).